# How to inject structure data script tag per Page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, structured-data

I'm using **Next.js 13** app router.
I want to add structure data for each page separately because each page has different metadata.

If I inject  in home page Layout file this tag will be present in each pages also if I add this to a **head tag** in Page.tsx I will get this error:

`Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

In Next.js 13 the **next/Head** did not work and I can not use it in Page.tsx to wrapping the script.

How can I add different structure data for each Page?